# Using Get-childitem to get list of files -like $pattern or newer than any file -like $pattern

Tags: powershell

as for now I have script to find files `-like '*ver1.0*'`, and it's working fine.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "D:\path\" | where {($_ -like "*$version*.sql")}
```

List of files:

```
file_ver1.0_xx.sql
file_ver1.0_xy.sql
```

But now I need to find files which look like before OR it's newer than it.

For example, I need to find files with pattern: `*ver1.0*` or `*ver0.9*` whose `LastWriteTime` is newer than any `*ver1.0*` file.

Comment: Why not create a function that takes version pattern and sort order as parameters?

Comment: Do you need the more recent file(s) with the lower version number on top of the other files, or should they be listed instead of some other file(s)?

Comment: I need list of files with latest version + files with older version, but uploaded after latest version (I know it's stupid and complicated)

Answer (score 1):

For performance reasons I'd enumerate the files just once, determine the most recent modification date of the files with `$version`, then filter for files with `$version` and files with a different version but newer date:

```
$allFiles = Get-ChildItem 'D:\path' -Filter '*.sql' |
            Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }

$refDate = $allFiles | Where-Object {
    $_.BaseName -like "*$version*"
} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1 -Expand LastWriteTime

$files = $allFiles | Where-Object {
    $_.BaseName -like "*$version*" -or
    ($_.BaseName -notlike "*$version*" -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt $refDate)
}
```

If you need to actually compare version numbers you probably need a somewhat more elaborate approach, though, e.g. like this:

```
$pattern    = 'ver(\d\.\d)'
$refVersion = [version]'1.0'

$allFiles = Get-ChildItem 'D:\path' -Filter '*.sql' |
            Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }

$refDate = $allFiles | Where-Object {
    $_.BaseName -match $pattern -and
    [version]$matches[1] -eq $refVersion
} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1 -Expand LastWriteTime

$files = $allFiles | Where-Object {
    $_.BaseName -match $pattern -and
    ([version]$matches[1] -eq $refVersion -or
    ([version]$matches[1] -lt $refVersion -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt $refDate))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that's ugly, but it works.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "D:\path" | where {($_ -like "*$version*.sql")}
$files += Get-ChildItem "D:\path" | where {($_ -like "*.sql" -notlike "*$version*.sql" -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt $files[0].LastWriteTime)}
```